# Counting occurrences of values per key in a multidimensional php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm seeking a little help with counting values in a multidimensional array.

I have an array key which will be something like "barrack obama" - and the values will be a long list of numbers.

then the next array key might be something like "another name" and the values will also be a long list of numbers.

Up to around 10 array keys all similarly arranged.

Example var_dump:

```
array(10) { ["barack obama"]=> array(4260) { [0]=> string(2) "19" [1]=>    string(2) "92" [2]=> string(2) "27" [3]=> string(2) "55" [4]=> string(2) "56" [5]=> string(2) "57" [6]=> string(4) "1409" [7]=> string(4) "1384" [8]=> string(4) "1362" [9]=> string(4) "1345" [10]=> string(4) "1280" } 
 ["united states"]=> array(5886) { [0]=> string(2) "72" [1]=> string(2) "81" [2]=> string(2) "89" [3]=> string(2) "90" [4]=> string(2) "92" [5]=> string(2) "21" [6]=> string(2) "23" [7]=> string(2) "27" [8]=> string(2) "32" [9]=> string(2) "47" [10]=> string(2) "55" }
```

How can I count the amount of times a unique value (numbers) occurred across my array keys (names).

so if 55 was in both "barack obama" and "united states" it would score 2.

Ideally I'd like to only keep values that appeared in one or more keys, but I can handle that after I have at least scored values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a results array. Then iterate the outer array, and inside the loop iterate the child array and increment the results array accordingly:

```
$data = array(
    "barack obama"  =>  array(0,50,150,250,600,900,45,150,1050),
    "tom jones"     =>  array(80,120,150,75,250,80,1100,1900),
    "bob mugabe"    =>  array(50,120,10,0,250,900,600,45,1000,1010),
);    

$results = array(); // create an empty array to store our results
foreach ( $data as $item ): // loop the outer array
    foreach ( $item as $key => $value ): // loop the inner array
        if ( array_key_exists($value,$results) ){ // check if value is already in results, if not set to 1, otherwise increment
            $results[$value] = $results[$value] + 1;
        } else { 
            $results[$value] = 1;
        }

    endforeach;
endforeach;

// show our results array
print "<pre>";
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Thanks - very nice!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the multi-dimensional array like this:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    'barack_obama' => array('19', '92', '27', '55', '57', '1409', '1384', '1362', '1345', '1280'),
    'united_states' => array('72', '81', '89', '90', '92', '21', '23', '27', '32', '47', '55'),
);

$aggregator = [];
foreach (array_keys($data) as $i) {
    for ($j = 0, $entryCount = count($data[$i]); $j < $entryCount; $j++) {
        $index = $data[$i][$j];
        $aggregator[$index] = isset($aggregator[$index]) ? $aggregator[$index] + 1 : 1;
    }
}
var_export($aggregator);
```

The result:

```
array ( 19 => 1, 92 => 2, 27 => 2, 55 => 2, 57 => 1, 1409 => 1, 1384 => 1, 1362 => 1, 1345 => 1, 1280 => 1, 72 => 1, 81 => 1, 89 => 1, 90 => 1, 21 => 1, 23 => 1, 32 => 1, 47 => 1, )
```